# Form and accents

Tags: html, forms, encoding

I have a form that doesn't work properly when I input somehting with an accent.

If I input "bâtiment", for instance, in the form, I'm sent to
**formation.php?search=b%E2timent**, instead of **formation.php?search=bâtiment**

What could cause that ?

**EDIT**

I have another form that sends me correctly to **something.php?search=bâtiment**, with the accent in the URL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%E2` is how you represent `â` in a URL.

It will be decoded automatically in `$_GET['search']`

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it back on the far end using `$search=url_decode($_REQUEST['search']);` URL specs say you can't use accent characters as valid URI characters so they are URL encoded on the fly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the page encoding.

Are you sure of what encoding you are using
%E2 is a latin1 encoding of â but many code use the windows cp1252.
Try to use %c6%92 (the utf8 encoding of â) and (%83, cp1252)